# Avoid automatic scroll in RecyclerView when updating list

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a pretty normal RecyclerView with a list of books.
In the UI it's possible to sort the books by title asc or dec. When I sort the list, it's sorted and then passed on to the adapter through a diffUtil, which works great - the items swap place etc etc.

However, it also scrolls the entire recyclerview. It seems like whatever book is currently at the top of the recyclerview (not the first item in the list, but the item currently rendered in the top of the recyclerview) will dictate the scroll position of the recyclerview. If I'm at the top of the recycler view, then sort the items (let's say that the top item is "Book ABC", the recyclerview will now scroll down to make sure that "Book ABC" is still being rendered at the top of the current view.

How can I make sure that the scroll position of the recycler view will just stay where it is whenever I update the list by sorting?

**Edit - code example**

In the fragment, I collect a stateflow which contains the updated (sorted) list:

```
...
stateflow.collect{
    // ...
    adapter.differ.submitList(it.borrowedItems)
    // ...
}
```

In the adapter, I have this function for the diffUtil:

```
private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<BorrowedItem>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: BorrowedItem, newItem: BorrowedItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem.itemId == newItem.itemId
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: BorrowedItem, newItem: BorrowedItem): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
}

val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)
```

Comment: Can you add some code that shows how you notify the adapter about the new changes? This way we can help you better.

Comment: @MennoSpijker I have added an example.

Comment: Also an update: the view only scrolls whenever the items switch place. It does not happen when an item is updated (but stays in the same place).